# How to "grep" entire line from file using Select-String?

Tags: powershell

The example below filters the line in the Get-Command which includes the string "Child".  Just the Get-ChildItem command is returned.  That is not the entire line though.  How do I select the entire line which includes the string "Child"?

```
PS C:\Users> Get-Command | Select-String Child

Get-ChildItem
```

Comment: you are _forcing_ the output of `Get-Command` into a string ... but the actual output IS NOT A STRING. [*grin*] it's at least one object with many properties. if you want the whole object, use `Where-Object`. ///// please remember that what is shown on the screen IS NOT the actual object ... it is a text representation of all/part of the object.

Answer (score 2):

The output you see is not a string. It is 4 properties of the object produced by `Get-Command`. To force it into a string you can use `Out-String` but you must add `-Stream` otherwise it will be all one string. Then you can "grep" it.

```
Get-Command | Out-String -Stream | Select-String 'child'

Function        Get-SFTPChildItem               2.2        Posh-SSH
Cmdlet          Get-ChildItem                   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
```

Comment: Here's all I'm trying to do.  Forget about the Get-Command command.  I'm simply trying to "grep" the output of the command and get the entire line like:

PS C:\Users\bernie> Get-Command | findstr ChildItem
Cmdlet          Get-ChildItem                                      7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management

Comment: Nicely done. Note that built-in function `oss` is essentially a shortcut to `Out-String -Stream`. Even then, however, you wouldn't expect to need this extra to-string-conversion step, and eliminating it is the subject of [GitHub suggestion #10726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726).

Comment: Mind if I add that to my answer? I didn't know that!

Answer (score 1):

Use the right tool for the job.

As noted, PowerShell is an object-oriented language, not a string-based one like bash.  It expects and will emit only objects. To dig for info about functions, cmdlets, files, folders, et al, you need to use the correct approach. Get-Command brings back cmdlet objects.

```
Get-Command | 
Select -First 1 | 
Get-Member
# Results
<#
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.AliasInfo

Name                MemberType     Definition                                                                                                                            
----                ----------     ----------                                                                                                                            
Equals              Method         bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                                        
GetHashCode         Method         int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                     
GetType             Method         type GetType()                                                                                                                        
ResolveParameter    Method         System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata ResolveParameter(string name)                                                          
ToString            Method         string ToString()                                                                                                                     
CommandType         Property       System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes CommandType {get;}                                                                          
Definition          Property       string Definition {get;}                                                                                                              
Description         Property       string Description {get;set;}                                                                                                         
Module              Property       psmoduleinfo Module {get;}                                                                                                            
ModuleName          Property       string ModuleName {get;}                                                                                                              
Name                Property       string Name {get;}                                                                                                                    
Options             Property       System.Management.Automation.ScopedItemOptions Options {get;set;}                                                                     
OutputType          Property       System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName] OutputType {get;}                          
Parameters          Property       System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata] Parameters {get;}                        
ParameterSets       Property       System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[System.Management.Automation.CommandParameterSetInfo] ParameterSets {get;}          
ReferencedCommand   Property       System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo ReferencedCommand {get;}                                                                     
RemotingCapability  Property       System.Management.Automation.RemotingCapability RemotingCapability {get;}                                                             
ResolvedCommand     Property       System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo ResolvedCommand {get;}                                                                       
Source              Property       string Source {get;}                                                                                                                  
Version             Property       version Version {get;}                                                                                                                
Visibility          Property       System.Management.Automation.SessionStateEntryVisibility Visibility {get;set;}                                                        
MSDN                ScriptMethod   System.Object MSDN();                                                                                                                 
DisplayName         ScriptProperty System.Object DisplayName {get=if ($this.Name.IndexOf('-') -lt 0)...                                                                  
HelpUri             ScriptProperty System.Object HelpUri {get=$oldProgressPreference = $ProgressPreference...                                                            
ResolvedCommandName ScriptProperty System.Object ResolvedCommandName {get=$this.ResolvedCommand.Name;} 
#>
```

If you want a cmdlet of a given name, do this, not Select-String, then this...

```
Get-Command -Name '*Child*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

or this... (the above is far faster and the way to do this type of lookup)

```
(Get-Command) -match 'Child' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
CommandType Name                                           Version   Source                         
----------- ----                                           -------   ------                         
Alias       Export-AdlStoreChildItemProperties             6.2.1     AzureRM.DataLakeStore          
Alias       Get-AdlStoreChildItem                          6.2.1     AzureRM.DataLakeStore          
Alias       Get-AdlStoreChildItem                          5.1.0     AzureRM.DataLakeStore          
Alias       Get-AdlStoreChildItemSummary                   6.2.1     AzureRM.DataLakeStore          
Function    Add-ChildControl                               1.5       ShowUI                         
Function    Get-ChildControl                               1.5       ShowUI                         
Function    Get-RemoteRegistryChildItem                    1.3.6     PowerShellCookbook             
Function    Get-SFTPChildItem                              2.2       Posh-SSH                       
Function    Remove-ChildControl                            1.5       ShowUI                         
Cmdlet      Export-AzureRmDataLakeStoreChildItemProperties 6.2.1     AzureRM.DataLakeStore          
Cmdlet      Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreChildItem              6.2.1     AzureRM.DataLakeStore          
Cmdlet      Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreChildItemSummary       6.2.1     AzureRM.DataLakeStore          
Cmdlet      Get-CDIRObjectChild                            3.3.618.0 AWSPowerShell                  
Cmdlet      Get-ChildItem                                  3.1.0.0   Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet      Get-ChildItem2                                 4.2.6     NTFSSecurity                   
Cmdlet      Get-ORGChild                                   3.3.618.0 AWSPowerShell
#>
```

If you want a specific command, then you have to state that

```
Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem
```

Select-String is only for emitted string results or serialized text-based files, etc.

To do this...

```
Get-Command | 
Select-String Child
```

...you'd have to make it a string first, as per Doug Maurer's helpful answer, and that is unnecessary work for this use case, (depending on what you are doing with it later) very slow and depending on how you do it can be error-prone to deal with

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Select-String).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Select-String).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Select-String -Examples
# Results
<#
"Hello","HELLO" | Select-String -Pattern "HELLO" -CaseSensitive
Select-String -Path "*.xml" -Pattern "the the"
Select-String -Path "$pshome\en-US\*.txt" -Pattern "@"
function search-help
$Events = Get-EventLog -LogName application -Newest 100
$Events | Select-String -InputObject {$_.message} -Pattern "failed"
Get-ChildItem c:\windows\system32\*.txt -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "Microsoft" -CaseSensitive
Select-String -Path "process.txt" -Pattern "idle, svchost" -NotMatch
$F = Select-String -Path "audit.log" -Pattern "logon failed" -Context 2, 3
$F.count
($F)[0].context | Format-List
$A = Get-ChildItem $pshome\en-us\about*.help.txt | Select-String -Pattern "transcript"
$B = Get-ChildItem $pshome\en-us\about*.help.txt | Select-String -Pattern "transcript" -AllMatches
$A
$B
$A.matches
Groups   : {Transcript}
$B.matches
Groups   : {Transcript}
Groups   : {Transcript}
#>
Get-help -Name Select-String -Full
Get-help -Name Select-String -Online

# Find all cmdlets / functions with a target parameter
Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet |
Where-Object {
    Try {$PSItem.parameters.keys -match 'credential'}
    Catch{} 
}|
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available cmdlets which has a specific parameter'

Get-Command -CommandType Function |
Where-Object {
    Try {$PSItem.parameters.keys -match 'credential'}
    Catch{} 
}|
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available functions which has a specific parameter'

# Get property enums/options for a specifc cmdlet/function
(Get-Service | Select-Object -First 1).Status.GetType()
[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::
GetNames([System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to return the "get-childitem" command, then why not just pass "Get-childitem" as a parameter to "Get-command"?

```
Get-command Get-childitem
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know how to grep an entire line from a file or the output of a command.

Comment: Where-Object acts like grep in linux.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-command | where-object{$_.Name -eq 'Get-ChildItem'}
```

OUTPUT

```
CommandType     Name                                 Version    Source
-----------     ----                                 -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-ChildItem                        7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
```